# Implementing Java Interface - Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

Just getting started with Kotlin and and I have read the official documentation, I am having issues implementing an interface from a library in kotlin.

Here is the interface in java :

```
public interface ResultCallBack {
    void detailsRetrieved(Obj var1, AnotherInterface var2);

    void anotherDataRetrieved(int var1, AnotherInterface var2);
}
```

the method I am calling from kotlin is like this :

```
 public static void startLibActivity(Context context, ResultCallBack callback) {
        sLuhnCallback = callback;
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, Library.class));
    }
```

how do i call `startLibActivity` from kotlin and implement `ResultCallBack` as well

I think I am stuck with this trial :

`Library.startLibActivity(activity, {})`

I have tried many possibilities within `{}` , still having issues with the right implementation.

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: What does your Kotlin code look like?

Comment: @Makoto I just updated the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your java interface is not a SAM [Functional Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html), so you can't using lambda expression `{}` in Kotlin directly.

You can [implement a Java interface](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html#implementing-interfaces) in Kotlin, for example:

```
class KotlinResultCallBack : ResultCallBack {
    override fun detailsRetrieved(var1: Obj?, var2: AnotherInterface?) = TODO()

    override fun anotherDataRetrieved(var1: Int, var2: AnotherInterface?) = TODO()
}
```

Then you can call the `startLibActivity` method as below:

```
startLibActivity(context, KotlinResultCallBack())
```

You can also use an [object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions) to create an anonymous class instance which implements a Java interface, for example:

```
startLibActivity(context, object : ResultCallBack {
    override fun detailsRetrieved(var1: Obj?, var2: AnotherInterface?) = TODO()

    override fun anotherDataRetrieved(var1: Int, var2: AnotherInterface?) = TODO()
})
```

Comment: thanks. This works ! Will accept the answer in 5 mins

Comment: @belvi Not at all.